# Is it bad form to intentionally throw an exception?

Tags: java, android, json, exception

Is it bad form to do something you know will throw an exception (assuming you handle it properly)? For example:

```
 JSONArray stuff = new JSONArray();
 JSONArray otherStuff = new JSONArray();
 try{
     for(i = 0; i < stuff.length(); i++){
         JSONObject a = stuff.getJSONObject(i);
         otherStuff.add(a);          
      }
 } catch (JSONException e){
     Log.e("FAIL", e.toString());
 }

//more code adding things to array later on
```

In this case the first time you ran the sequence the array would be empty and getJSONObject would throw an excpetion because there would be nothing at index i. However, later on, if things were added to the array, it would not throw an exception.

Granted this code is just a hypothetical (I'm sure there are better examples - someone may have one) but as a matter of form/style is it ok to intentionally throw an exception? Or should you just avoid throwing them all together?

Comment: It is ok , but generally you shouldn't. This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314358/design-issue-to-what-extent-should-i-rely-on-exceptions-for-the-flow-of-control)

Comment: I disagree that it is ok, but agree with what is in that post

Comment: The current sample wouldn't throw. You wouldn't enter the loop because stuff.length() == 0. That said, just logging isn't usually proper exception handling. Either the case is valid and should be handled normally, or it isn't and you should likely be doing more than just ignoring it.

Comment: Ok so my example is bad. I was trying to come up with something to illustrate the question. I guess I'm trying to understand are exceptions supposed to be used only to indicate something bad happened or is there a legitimate purpose outside of logging error messages and the like.

Comment: They are usually used for more than just logging error messages. For instance if a stream were to die for an unexpected reason you would want to catch it, close it cleanly and then get back to a valid state. You would also want to log, but that's not usually the main goal. Exception handling should usually entail handling, which can often mean more than just ignoring or logging.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience it's generally considered bad practice to use Exceptions as flow control. They should be reserved for Exceptional situations.

Comment: one could say exceptions are only for EXCEPTIONal situations (bad joke)

Comment: yeah that's why I chose the word exceptional, I just left it a little more understated :)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is ok, if the exception is only thrown in exceptional cases and not as a regular way to e.g. quit a loop.

But be aware: create, throw and than catch an exception is not fast.

=> If possible (and not too complicated, I would highly recommend not to use an Exception.